# Rotating div with left and right edges slanted/cut back to parallel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use this function to rotate div:

```
function connect(x1,y1,x2,y2,color,thickness) {
    var length = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1) * (x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1)));// distance
    var cx = ((x1 + x2) / 2) - (length / 2);// center
    var cy = ((y1 + y2) / 2) - (thickness / 2);// center
    var angle = Math.atan2((y1-y2),(x1-x2))*(180/Math.PI);// angle
    var htmlLine = '<div style="height:'+thickness+'px; background-color:'+color+';line-height:1px;position:absolute;left:'+cx+'px;top:'+cy+'px;width:'+length+'px;transform:rotate('+angle+'deg);"></div>';
    document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine;
}
```

How can I cut-off edges from that div, so that left and right side stays parallel to the screen?

Take a look at the picture to understand what I'm going for

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `transform: skew(ax, ay)` with `ax == 0`
*or* `transform: skewY(ay)`
:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  transform: skew(0, 20deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

In your case, if you intend to keep your `connect` function the same, just replace `rotate` in your transform call with `skewY`:

```js
function connect(x1,y1,x2,y2,color,thickness) {
    var length = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1) * (x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1)));// distance
    var cx = ((x1 + x2) / 2) - (length / 2);// center
    var cy = ((y1 + y2) / 2) - (thickness / 2);// center
    var angle = Math.atan2((y1-y2),(x1-x2))*(180/Math.PI);// angle
    var htmlLine = '<div style="height:'+thickness+'px; background-color:'+color+';line-height:1px;position:absolute;left:'+cx+'px;top:'+cy+'px;width:'+length+'px;transform:skewY('+angle+'deg);"></div>';
    document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine;
}

connect(0, 0, 300, 40, 'green', 10);
```

Comment: `transform: skewY(20deg);` can be used too.

Comment: Great, that's it! I was trying something with skew but couldn't do it. Thank you!

Comment: I knew there was an easier way, instead of using pseudo element to hide those parts.